# Last row in a Polymer grid layout

Tags: html, css, polymer, dart-polymer

I am currently trying to make a grid layout with polymer.

```
   <div layout wrap horizontal justified class="projects">
      <template repeat="{{project in team['projects']}}">
        <item project="{{project['id']}}">
            <div>{{project['name']}}</div>
        </item>
      </template>
  </div>
```

It works great for all rows but the last one. The last row, which does not contain enough elements to fill the row completely, distributes it's children evenly in the row due to the 'justified' attribute. However, I want them to have the same space between each other as the items in the other rows and align to the left so that they won't fill the whole row.

For my understading this doesn't work with the attribute 'justified'. But what can I use to make it work? I just cannot find a solution.

An example of this problem can be found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/grid.html).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like that you are using "space-around" .. You should use "flex-start". A good tool to preview your flex boxes is here : http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Here is a link with an example: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=wrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=flex-start&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. where you can use markup to create fancy looking buttons.